# Is it possible to set UIDatePicker to only days (exclude hours, minutes and seconds)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uidatepicker

I'm trying to have a UIDatePicker to present only the date, month and year to the user. I want to avoid presenting them with the hours, minutes and seconds like it comes by default. I've tried looking for something that might help but can only find solutions that aren't explained clearly in Objective-C, however I'm coding in Swift. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ideas?  Read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to chose the mode of the date picker

```
@IBOutlet weak var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myDatePicker.datePickerMode = .date // or .Date (Swift 2.x)
}
```

[date picker options](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDatePickerMode) .

> Declaration SWIFT

```
var datePickerMode: UIDatePickerMode
```

> Discussion The
>   value of this property indicates the mode of a date picker. It
>   determines whether the date picker allows selection of a date, a time,
>   both date and time, or a countdown time. The default mode is
>   UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime. See Date Picker Mode for a list of mode
>   constants.

[UIDatePickerMode](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDatePickerMode)

> The mode of the date picker.

Declaration Constants

Time

The date picker displays hours, minutes, and (optionally) an AM/PM designation. The exact items shown and their order depend upon the locale set. An example of this mode is [ 6 | 53 | PM ].

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Date

The date picker displays months, days of the month, and years. The exact order of these items depends on the locale setting. An example of this mode is [ November | 15 | 2007 ].

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

DateAndTime

The date picker displays dates (as unified day of the week, month, and day of the month values) plus hours, minutes, and (optionally) an AM/PM designation. The exact order and format of these items depends on the locale set. An example of this mode is [ Wed Nov 15 | 6 | 53 | PM ].

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

CountDownTimer

The date picker displays hour and minute values, for example [ 1 | 53 ]. The application must set a timer to fire at the proper interval and set the date picker as the seconds tick down.

Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using storyboards just change mode to "date" in the Attributes inspector.

Answer (score 1):

```
YourPickerView.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;
```