# Displaying the Day Of The Week From Date Picker

Tags: xcode, swift, datepicker, uidatepicker

I want to store just the day of the week as a string using a datePicker in xcode using swift.

Comment: the name of the day or the position number 1-7 for the week ( sunday = 1...saturday = 7) ?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus Name of the Day

Comment: do you need to know how to use the date picker also?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27220344/2303865

Comment: but how do you use this with a datePicker, this will only give the current day, no? @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: No. You can use it with any NSDate Object.

Comment: Just pick any NSDate object and extract the name of the weekday using this extension.

Comment: 'NSDate' does not have a member named 'descriptionWithCalendarFormat' @LeonardoSavioDabus

Comment: Important NSCalendarDate is deprecated in Mac OS X v10.6 and later. For calendrical calculations, you should use suitable combinations of NSCalendar, NSDate, and NSDateComponents, as described in Calendars, Date Components, and Calendar Units https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendarDate_Class/NSCalendarDate_Class.pdf

Comment: Nolan Betts I have updated the answer, with an extension that works with iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var strWeekday: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // set mode to date only
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

        // add target for the trigger update function to change the weekday when the user changes the date
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(triggerUpdate), for: .valueChanged)

        // weekday initial value
        strWeekday.text = datePicker.date.weekdayNameStandalone
    }

    @IBAction func triggerUpdate(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
        strWeekday.text = datePicker.date.weekdayNameStandalone
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Date {

    // returns weekday name (Sunday-Saturday Localized) as String
    var weekdayNameStandalone: String {
        Formatter.weekdayNameStandalone.string(from: self)
    }

    // returns weekday name (Sunday-Saturday fixed locale en_US_POSIX) as String
    var weekdayNameStandAlonePosix: String {
        Formatter.weekdayNameStandAlonePosix.string(from: self)
    }

}
```

---

```
extension Formatter {

    static let weekdayNameStandalone: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = .autoupdatingCurrent
        formatter.dateFormat = "cccc"
        return formatter
    }()

    static let weekdayNameStandAlonePosix: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "cccc"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func displayDay(sender: AnyObject) {
        // grab the selected date from the date picker
        var chosenDate = self.datePicker.date

        // create an NSDateFormatter
        var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"

        // grab the day and create a message
        let day = formatter.stringFromDate(chosenDate)
        let result = "That was a \(day)"

        // create alert controller
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: result, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        // add an "OK" button
        myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        // show the alert
        self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```