# Add weekday to UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

Is there a way to add the day of the week to my UIDatePicker? I would like to show if the date chosen is a Monday or Tuesday etc.

```
 let picker = UIDatePicker()
func createDatePicker(){

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))


    toolbar.setItems([done], animated: false)

    dateField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    dateField.inputView = picker

    picker.datePickerMode = .date

}

@objc func donePressed(){

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: picker.date)

    dateField.text = "\(dateString)"
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326196/displaying-the-day-of-the-week-from-date-picker

Comment: Do not re-purpose question posts for new questions please. This site tries to build a repository of questions and answers *for future visitors to benefit from*, and that means that once a question is answered, you can't just replace the question text with a different text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to show day of the week in `UIDatePicker` is to set the `datePickerMode` to `dateAndTime`. Alternatively, you can create your custom `datePicker` using `UIPickerView`. However, that would be a cumbersome approach.