# Weekday from UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I want to set my dateField Label to show both the date as well as the weekday. Currently it only shows the date. I attempted to follow this question [Displaying the Day Of The Week From Date Picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326196/displaying-the-day-of-the-week-from-date-picker) but it is not the solution for my case.

[image]

```
 let picker = UIDatePicker()
func createDatePicker(){

    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))

    toolbar.setItems([done], animated: false)

    dateField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    dateField.inputView = picker
    picker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime

}
 @objc func donePressed(){

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .none
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: picker.date)


    dateField.text = "\(dateString)"
    showTime()
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

   @objc func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker){
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
    formatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
    dateField.text = formatter.string(from: sender.date)

}
func showTime(){

    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none
    formatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    timeField.text = formatter.string(from: picker.date)

}
```

Comment: So really your question has nothing to do with a date picker. Your question really is about how to format a `Date` to show a medium format date with the addition of the weekday, correct?

Comment: my date picker shows the day of the week, I am trying to add the day of the week to my dateField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is really just about how to format a `Date` to show a medium date format plus the weekday.

The only standard date style that shows the weekday is the `.full` format but that is not what you want.

One solution is to set a specific `dateFormat` such as `yyyy-MM-dd, EEE` but you want a format appropriate for the user's locale.

The following will do what you need:

```
@objc func donePressed(){
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    // MMMddyyyy is essentially the same as the "medium" format
    formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMddyyyyEEE")
    let dateString = formatter.string(from: picker.date)

    dateField.text = "\(dateString)"
    showTime()
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

In the USA, the format will become: "EEE, MMM dd, yyyy". In other locales it will show whatever is appropriate.