# How to DatePicker with Year Month day time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uidatepicker

How to get DatePicker |Year|Day Date Month|Time Min|Second|AM PM| ?
Default DatePicker Showing its showing |Day Date Month | Min | Seconds|

Answer (score 0):

Date picker is a very high level component and does not allow explicit setting of display in any way. There are properties you can play around with such as `datePickerMode` and `locale`. For your case I guess you should find a correct `locale`.

This is not advised though. The thing is that `locale` is set automatically or it should be set to whatever makes sense to user which world-wide depends on the user. If you override this functionality you will most likely confuse users.

Anyway if you can't get the result you want with date picker you will have to user a normal picker view and manage sections and rows yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some how close to your desired requirement  by setting `DatePicker's`  `datePickerMode` property

```
myDatePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
```

see the more available  datepicker mode .[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27220344/4466607)

Comment: @Its not showing Year and AM\PM option in iphone device -> iPhone 6s, its shows only AM|PM option in simulator iphone 5s.  I do not see year yet "    _datePicker_QuitDate.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
"

Answer (score 0):

UIDatePicker takes device Time format. If you have 24 hour Date format selected in your device, the UIDatePicker will not show AM/PM and show the time in 24hr. format. So you have to change the Time format of the device to 12 hour format. We can not set the time format of the UIDatePicker.